# Angular - single http request returns large volume, is there any way to flush records in batches?

Tags: angular, promise, observable

I've an Observable which returns data from an external API.
I'll then store required fields to an array and which will then get displayed on UI.

It works fine for smaller volumes (5-10k), but for large volumes (100k+) the UI will freeze/hang waiting for the Observable to return entire 100k.

Is there any way to push/flush 10k records each (or flush every 10 seconds) to UI, while the observable/promise contue to fetch remaining records from API, please?

```
//Observable to get data
getData(url): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(url); //Returns 100k+ records
}

//Store values to array for displaying in UI
this.service.getData(url).then((data:any) => {
    const displayObject = [];
    data.forEach(element => {
        displayObject.push(element.id,element.name);
    }
}
```

Tried with Promise also, but same result:

```
//Promise to get data
async getDataAsync(url){
    return await this.http.post(url).toPromise();
}

//Store values to array for displaying in UI
this.service.getDataAsync(url).then((data:any) => {
    const displayObject = [];
    data.forEach(element => {
        displayObject.push(element.id,element.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better done in API's side. Is it possible in your external API to fetch each record individually instead (eg. `this.http.post(url/1)`, `this.http.post(url/2)` and so on)? Or better a range of data (eg. `this.http.post(url?start=1&end=5000)`)?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelD, it is an external API, need to check fallibility with the API owner. I was trying to find a way from Angular side, so that we can avoid the dependency on API changes.

Comment: If you could poll a range of data in the API, then you could do a buffered sequential requests that reduces the load in the front-end. But if you were to ping a huge dataset in a single request, it could slow down the front-end.